# new user setup on ubuntu for hadoop?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, hadoop, ssh

i am trying to install hadoop on my ubuntu and followed the installation guide on the page but o keep getting confused on the very first step:

```
  enter c$ su 
   password: 
# useradd hadoop 
# passwd hadoop 
   New passwd: 
   Retype new passwd ode here
```

i get this is me creating a new user - hadoop. but for the very next step:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

am i running it from my main user or first su hadoop and then from there??
i tried from the first way and it doesn't work and i don't have hadoop on my /home yet. how can i add it there ??

Answer (score 0):

The hadoop control scripts rely on SSH to peform cluster-wide operations. For example, there is a script for stopping and starting all the daemons in the clusters. To work seamlessly, SSH needs to be setup to allow password-less login for the hadoop user from machines in the cluster. The simplest way to achive this is to generate a public/private key pair, and it will be shared across the cluster. That is the reason why you have these steps.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

First, you need to login to hadoop user.

Second, you configured ssh as above.

But I don't know what you mean about "i don't have hadoop on my /home yet". I guess you cannot create user hadoop. Please try adduser instead of useradd.

```
$ sudo adduser hadoop
```

[image]

I am not sure why useradd doesn't work. But I read from help document, it shows that "useradd is a low level utility for adding users"

[image]